# HTML table horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, uikit

I'm trying to fix a table in my laravel blade since it's so large extending horizontally to the right.

The data shows in the right columns for each header but It extends to far out and I'm trying to find the best way to align everything and contain in a horizontally scrollable table container.

I'm using UI kit in laravel currently.

Basically, I have 6 main headers. The first of which has 5 child headings, and the other 5 main headers each have 6 child headers. Of course, the data follows the same (5 columns, 6,6,6,6,6)

Anyway, I'm not familiar with the best way to keep this format and contain it with horizontal scroll using UI kit. There may be a more clearly defined way using that or I may just need raw CSS, but I'm hoping there is a way that works well in UI kit.

The table:

```
<div class="md-card-content">
    <table class="uk-table" style="table-layout: fixed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderOne</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderTwo</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderThree</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderFour</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderFive</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderSix</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a reason for using `table-layout: fixed`? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/23ss86nw/)?

Comment: Not really, I added it about an hour ago to see if it would constrain it correctly but it just cramped everything together, which is the opposite problem. When I remove it it just extends too far to the right

Comment: ok just wanted to know if it was required or not. does the link in my previous comment have what you want?

Comment: Whoa that's perfect!  I've been stying the table only, not the card content. Thanks so much! If you put an answer for it I'll accept it ASAP

Comment: You can accept the answer @jdickel provided... its the same pretty much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a container around your table to define a width for the displayed area and set an "x-overflow" to auto will be scrollable on the x-axis (according to the width of the table) automatically.

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" style="width: 500px">
  <div class="md-card-content" style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table class="uk-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderOne</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderTwo</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderThree</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderFour</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderFive</th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">HeaderSix</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-1</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-2</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-3</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-4</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-5</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
            <th>child-header-6</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>1-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>2-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>3-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>4-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>5-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
                <td>6-data</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```